# SOAP UI error from setup groovy script

Tags: soap, xpath, groovy, soapui

SOAP UI error from setup groovy script

It is something wrong when I define the first string from the `setNodeValue` method.  The XPath is not correct or I might be missing something.

Any ideas?

```
Error : org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException:error:Unexpected element: CDATA
```

SOAP Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:log="Logisense_EngageIP">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <log:AuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:Username>vv</log:Username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:Password>vv</log:Password>
      </log:AuthHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <log:CreateUser>
         <!--Optional:  DYNAMIC VALUE -->
         <log:username>${username}</log:username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:password>test</log:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:alternativeUsername>de</log:alternativeUsername>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:roleName>admin</log:roleName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:cultureName>English</log:cultureName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:languageName>English</log:languageName>
         <!--Optional: -->
         <log:ownerUsername>admin</log:ownerUsername>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:parentUsername></log:parentUsername>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:userStatusTypeName>Enabled</log:userStatusTypeName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:creditRatingName>Default</log:creditRatingName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <log:billGroupName>Default</log:billGroupName>
         <log:expireDate>2015-09-12</log:expireDate>
      </log:CreateUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Groovy script setup :

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("CreateUserRequest1#Request")
holder.setNodeValue("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/log:CreateUser/log:username","Jose Amaral")
holder.updateProperty()
```

Comment: Try `.setNodeValue("//*:CreateUser/*:username", ...`

Comment: Are you putting an accent on the e in Jose?  It sounds to me like somewhere in the path, some process is doing CDATA wrapping, and the SOAP service doesn't like it.

Comment: The **.setNodeValue("//*:CreateUser/*:username", ...** did not work.  I got the same CDATA error.

Comment: @DenisDeO I think it's an encoding problem... did you check your system encoding? and your request encoding (see `Encoding` property in `TestRequest properties` tab on your request).